# How to remove sprite in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

In `cocos2d` I created `SPRITE` but after click on menu Button I want to remove sprite.
 this is sprite code..

```
// create and initialize our seeker sprite, and add it to this layer
seeker1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"button_Red.png"];
seeker1.position = ccp( 50, 150 );
[self addChild:seeker1];
```

And also I create menu.

```
    CCMenuItemImage * menuItem1 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"1.gif"
                                                         selectedImage: @"2.gif"
                                                                target:self
                                                              selector:@selector(doSomethingOne:)];
```

And This is remove code so what I done wrong in Remove.

```
- (void) doSomethingOne: (CCMenuItem  *) menuItem 
{
 NSLog(@"The first menu was called");
[self.children removeObject:seeker1];// removeSpriteFrames:seeker1 removeChild:seeker1 cleanup:YES];
}
```

Please give me code for how to remove sprite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
[seeker1 removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
```

Comment: `seeker1.opacity = 0;
    id a1 = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:5.0f];
    id a2 = [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:0.4f];
    [seeker1 runAction:[CCSequence actions:a1,a2,nil]];
    [self addChild:seeker1];`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of
`[self.children removeObject:seeker1];`

use
`[self removeChild:seeker1 cleanup:YES];`

As you are adding child to `self`, then how can you remove it from `self.children`

Comment: create a selector and call that after 5 second, in that create and add your sprite.

Comment: @Muhammed Ayaz : Ask another question for this, coz it's complicated to understand it in comment

Comment: why don't you create another layer?